# Convergence of Hahn series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

Enumerate $\Bbb{Q}^+$ with $\Bbb{Z}^+$ by a bijiective map $f:\Bbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}^+$. Consider the Hahn series: $$P_f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_nx^{f(n)}$$ where $c_n \in \Bbb{C}$, $x \in \Omega = \Bbb{C} \setminus \Bbb{R}^-$ and each $x^{f(n)}$ is chosen as the holomorphic branch mapping $\Bbb{R}^+$ to $\Bbb{R}^+$. Note these series with finite support form a commutative ring without maximal ideals (and that is where I began to look into them).

With $f$ and $c_n$ given, I want to discuss 2 problems:

**Q1**: For classic power series, **non-absolute convergence only happens at the boundary of the convergence domain, which has Lebesgue measure $0$**. Does the same happen for $P_f$ with nontrivial convergence set? I know little about this question because rational indexes are too 'dense' -- construction of a counterexample may involve axiom of choice with which I am not familiar.

**Q2**: Nontrivial convergence domains of classic power series are always disk-shaped -- that is, a set between an open disk centered at $O$ and its closure. What shapes of nontrivial convergence domains of $P_f$ could be? Specifically, **does there exist $P_f$ which has path-disconnected convergence domains?** It is easy to prove that if $P_f$ converges absolutely for certain $|x|=r$, then $P_f$ absolutely converges in $\Omega \cap \{|x| \le r\}$, but like **Q1** it seems difficult to deal with non-absolute parts.

Comment: You can choose $f$ such that $f(2n)-f(2n-1)= O(1/n!)$ and $f(n)=o(\log n)$ then you'll have that for all $x>0$, $\sum_{n\ge 1}x^{f(n)} n^{-1/2}(-1)^{n+1} =\sum_{n\ge 0} e^{o(\log n)} ((2n-1)^{-1/2}-(2n)^{-1/2}) + O(1/n!) $ converges conditionally but not absolutely.

Comment: @reuns $f^{-1}(0)$ is not defined cause $f(n)>0$.

Comment: There is no point to exclude the constant term.

Comment: @reuns If you want to get a commutative ring without maximal ideals then it matters. Also, excluding constant term doesn't make a difference in its convergence. Due to these facts I got rid of it.